# What method call from Back button pressed of Android Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, restart, destroy

I read along [the documentation in this page.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) And obtaining clear picture of one activity starts in android. Just like this screenshot below:

[image]

Here is my case.

**Activity -A** called Intent to start **Activity B-.**
And then from **Activity -B** the user click **Back button.**
So then **it returned to Activity -A.**

my question is .... since now we're in that **Activity -A.**

Does onPaused() method called back or onResumed() method 
that is called now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ActivityB takes the foreground, Activity A is put into the stopped state (onPause and onStop will be called).  When ActivityA comes back, it will get onStart, followed by onResume.